# Squared Residuals equal Variance of Dependent Variable (ARMA-GARCH)

Tags: volatility, time-series, garch

My understanding of ARMA-GARCH models for a variable $X$ is as follows: I estimate a conditional mean of a variable $X$ by use of the ARMA part of the model. I estimate the conditional variance of variable $X$ by use of the GARCH part of the model.

And as far as I understand those models, this means that the variance of $X$ is simply interpreted as the squared residual of the mean model at a specific point in time.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. The conditional variance of $X_t$, conditional on the information up to and including time $t-1$, equals the conditional variance of the squared error:
$$
\text{Var}(X_t|I_{t-1})=\mathbb{E}(u_t^2|I_{t-1})
$$
where $u_t$ is the raw error. The squared residual $\hat u_t^2$ is a rather noisy proxy for it / estimate thereof.

The unconditional / long-run variance of $X$ depends on the ARMA-GARCH model but in any case is not equal to the square residual at any period, except when/if it is numerically equal, which is by chance.

Comment: Before accepting this as an answer: (1) Why is the conditional variance of the squared error simply the expected value of the squared error? (2) Why is the squared residual a noisy proxy for it? Does this "noisiness" still remain, even when assuming my conditional mean model true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @shenflow, (1) is by definition of $u_t$; $X_t=\mu_t+u_t$ where $\mu_t:=\mathbb{E}(X_t\mid I_{t-1})$ and so $\mathbb{E}(u_t\mid I_{t-1})=0$. (2) It just is, even for correctly specified conditional mean models; see Andersen & Bollerslev ["Answering the Skeptics: Yes, Standard Volatility Models do Provide Accurate Forecasts"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2527343) (1998) p. 889 and onwards. The magnitude of correlation between squared errors and true underlying volatilities may be pretty low (say, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3 or even 0.2) for plausible data generating processes.